# Jboss eap-6.0 rotating log files appear in bin directory

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, slf4j

I have 3 applications on jboss-eap-6.0 all are working OK, but one of them is creating rotating log files in the jboss /bin directory exactly at 0:00 always with 0 bytes

Everything else is logging correctly to the proper /log directory.

The configuration files are pretty similar between each other, just changes the filenames.
I suspect it has something to do with the dependency libraries... maybe log4j or slf4j that in this application are not included; i tried with log4j by now.

If someone has any idea about this issue or have saw this behavior somewhere else, it would be very useful to know.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI - since you are using EAP, you should consider opening a support ticket with Red Hat. You will have better luck getting an answer from them.

Comment: Do any of the applications have a log4j configuration file in them?

Comment: The applications have already log4j configurations working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like there is a Periodic Rotating File Handler configured that does not have any Log Categories logging to it. Those Handlers will generate a new file each time the date format changes, which would explain why you're getting a new file each night.

In the EAP 6.0 web based admin console click on Profiles in top right, then expand Core on the left and select Logging, then click the Handler tab and the Periodic sub tab. If Suffix is set to .yyyy-MM-dd that would give you a new file each day. File Path would be the actual file name of your log file, and the directory used would be given by the environment property shown under "File Relative To:".

If you want to change the directory used for the log file, then change the value of the environment property shown under "File Relative To", or change it to jboss.server.log.dir which I believe is the default.